# Asyncrhonous socket client

Tags: java, android, sockets, asynchronous

I'm developing an asynchronous socket client based on threads.  When the program calls `readLine()`, it blocks indefinitely and never returns.

```
public class ADNClient {

  Socket socket = null;
  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
  DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

  Thread listener = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      String line;
      try {
        // Stop here and doesn't progress
        while ((line = dataInputStream.readLine()) != null) {
          //DO something
        }
      } 
      catch (IOException e) {}
    });

    public ADNClient() {
    try {
      socket = new Socket("192.168.1.5", 5000);
      dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      listener.start();
      //sender.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("ADN", e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public void close() {
    listener.stop();
    try {
      socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("ADN", e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What data are you sending the client? Is it terminated with a newline character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I'm noob with IN/Outputstreams... I didn't send the newline character, the correct way to recive information  is using

```
readUTF()
```

instead of

```
readLine()
```

Thank you Greg Kopff!